# unspecified function parameter

Tags: c++, c++03

In [GManNickG's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3980926/558546) he used the notation:

```
template <typename>
static no& test(...);
```

Originally I thought this was just shorthand for "insert blah" and the user must substitute their own type:

```
template<typename>
static no& test(int);
```

However, after testing it in a compiler without any changes it worked! Additionally, overload resolution behaves as expected when using `...` vs. an explicit int in the context of the original question.

What is this called in C++03/how should I interpret this code? It looks close to C++11's variadic templates, but there are some obvious differences between the two.

Comment: The `...` is ellipsis (plural ellipses, I believe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, ellipses specify a variadic function (variable length argument list).  You can use the `va_start`, `va_arg`, and `va_end` macros to "pull" arguments out. You'll need an initial argument however; they need a starting place to begin grabbing arguments off of the stack (the `arg` before the ellipses + `sizeof(arg)`).

```
/* sum a bunch of ints */
int sum(int arg_cnt, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, arg_cnt);
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < arg_cnt; ++i) {
        sum += va_arg(ap, int);
    }
    va_end(ap);
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Initial interpretation? GManNickG is using SFINAE, where the ellipsis is used to control overload resolution.

Comment: @DyP: Oh, crap, missed that.  Fixed

Comment: You might want to add *why* it is used in SFINAE: An ellipsis conversion sequence (occurs when a function argument is matched with the ellipsis) is ranked as the worst implicit conversion sequence. Therefore, any other implicit conversion will be preferred by overload resolution, and this function overload (with the ellipsis) will only be considered if the other overloads don't match (in this example) or are not considered (e.g. because of a substitution failure).